# SSO using Identity Server and Openid

Tags: angular, authentication, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I am new to OpenId and Identity server.

Aim is to create a sub-domain for login, after login user is redirected to another sub-domain where it automatically authenticates.

```
eg: login is done from login.domain.com then redirects to application.domain.com
```

I am using .net-core Web-Api with angular 6 token authentication. One WeApi and angular for login app and another for main application. How can i achieve this using identity server and open id?

Comment: probably it would be easier to use asp.net website for login since it goes out of the box with identity server. then you can use js clients like node-openid-client for NodeJs and oidc-client-js for browser to connect to identity server.

Comment: @PavelAgarkov it will not be done it must be done with same technology

Comment: @Nighil - what do you mean by `One WeApi and angular for login app`?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Login is handled by a single application which has one UI which is done in Angular and API which is .netcore